# How should I go about comparing all rows in a sql table against a "master record" using vb.net?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Let's say, for example, this is a quiz where the answers are already loaded into a database from different students.  Inside of the table with various student entries containing various student's answers there is a row "masterentry" with all of the correct answers.

What I would like to do is code a button that will pull the master row on click and compare every other row against it. Starting with the first row, every time the column matches the master entry 1 point is assigned to a declared integer.  When the row has completely been read the integer is stored in a "totalpoints" column.  Then it moves on to the next row of answers.

I hope this makes sense the way I worded it, if there is an easier way to go about it I am open to suggestions.  I don't really need any help establishing the connection to the sql database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance for anyone's time.  I can provide more details if it would be helpful.

Comment: Can you indicate the schema a little better? What are the columns in the table and what are their datatypes? Can you show an example of the master row (not the real thing in case students are peeking here and get an advance look at the answers of course :-)) and a few examples of the answer rows?

Comment: I appreciate the help, I'm pretty new to all this and never have really gone the stored procedure route.  The columns are basically answer1, answer2, answer3 etc. up to 65.  The table is simply "quiz1".  Datatypes for answers are all nvarchar50 and allownulls with the exception of the primary key which is their name.  The master row is within the same table as the submitted answers and the only thing that is different about it is that the primary key "Name" column is "Masterentry".  Maybe I should have it stored in a separate table?

Comment: Seems fine in the same table, but if the answers are `nvarchar(50)`, that sounds a little dangerous to me. Could a quiz answer be `"Mary had a little lamb"` and a student's answer could be `"Marry had a little lamb"`? E.g. should spelling be ignored? Fuzzy search is going to be an issue - this approach is better suited to multiple choice, true/false, or numeric answers.

Comment: Yes, but the quiz answers are more of a selection of pre-written answers.  So there really isn't a likelihood of a misspelling, but definitely a good thought there.

Comment: Which may beg the question of why I initially submitted the full string of the selection instead of simply the selection number, to which I can't answer.  I will approach it differently next time around for sure...

Comment: So it sounds like you should store the text answers as a master somewhere, and record their choices (like 1,2,3,4 or A,B,C,D) with each quiz result. Not only will this reduce the fuzziness it will also substantially reduce storage costs and the efficiency of comparisons.

Comment: I suppose I will rewrite the initial storing of the answers then.  Again, I appreciate the help very much.

Comment: You may also consider an EAV model, e.g. instead of 65 columns, you just have `QuizID, StudentID, QuestionID, Answer`. So a quiz for a student will be represented by 65 rows. This will be easier to expand if you decide later that you want to have 80 questions instead of 65. It will also be similarly easy to insert data and to query against it. I wrote about EAV a bit here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway.aspx

Comment: You're the man...I'll definitely check that out soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a rough guess based on vague idea of schema. You would just call this query from .NET (preferably stored in stored procedure, passing in a `@QuizID`) unless you really want to do it less efficiently by looping after pulling all of the data to the client...

```
;WITH master AS (SELECT a1 = Answer1, a2 = Answer2, ...
  FROM dbo.Quiz
  WHERE QuizID = @QuizID
  AND Answer = 'masterentry'
)
SELECT a.StudentID,
    Score = CASE WHEN a.Answer1 = master.a1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          + CASE WHEN a.Answer2 = master.a2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          + ...
FROM dbo.Quiz AS a
CROSS JOIN master
WHERE a.QuizID = @QuizID
AND a.Answer <> 'masterentry' -- or a.StudentID IS NOT NULL?
```

There may be some shortcuts here based on the data types. E.g. if the quiz is true/false there are some little tricks you can do to reduce the `...` part.

Comment: I forgot to mark this as an answer, it helped me down the line.  I appreciate it.